# How do I create a guest account without actually placing it in the db in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, model

So I have a pretty typical user model, nothing special about it.  I'd like to be able to use this model as a guest user when no other user is logged in.

Is there a way to create a guest account, or some sort of default when no account is set, in CakePHP so that Auth contains that?

So, for example, the id would be set as 0, username would be set to guest, etc.

Thank you,
James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could override the `find` method at your `User` model, so that when `Auth` calls it (internally), you can intercept that and return whatever your want instead. Something like this (on your `User` model):

```
public function find($conditions, $fields, $order=null, $recursive=false) {
    $user = parent::find($conditions, $fields, $order, $recursive);
    if(empty($user)) {
        // No "real" user found, let's create "guest"
        $user = array(
            'User' => array(
                'id' => 0,
                'username' => 'guest'
                // add other fields as needed
            )
        );
    }
    return $user;
}
```

Comment: This looks interesting, I might be able to make this work.  I'll try to come back and update my results.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just add it to the session.

```
$this->Session->write(AuthComponent::$sessionKey, array(
  'User' => array(
    'id' => 0,
    'username' => 'guest'
   )
));
```

Comment: This would work, but it's a bit too.. well, blunt force, I'm trying to do it in a more smooth manner.  I think I may have found a solution though, thanks for your input!

Comment: Would love to see what you come up with!

Comment: You bet, once I get the kinks worked out I'll post it for others to use. :)

Answer (score 1):

In AppController :

```
public function beforeFilter() {    
    if(!$this->Auth->loggedIn()){
        $this->loadModel('User');
        $user = $this->User->findById(0); //Guest user id
        $this->Auth->login($user['User']);
    }
}
```

This works fine for me with CakePHP 2.2.
It allows permission configuration including guest's permission via a web interface : http://www.alaxos.net/blaxos/pages/view/plugin_acl_2.0